Any softwares that can give the condition for some polynomial system to have certain real solutions (with multiplicity?) without explicitly solving it
In particular, I need to confirm (rather than simply conjecture) that the following parameterized system has exactly eighteen distinct non-negative solutions (in other words, $\mathit{sys}\land{w,x,y,z}\geqslant0$ has $18$ real solutions) with respect to $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$ iff $t\in{\left(0,1\right)}$: $$\mathit{sys}≔\begin{cases}\displaystyle w+x+y+z\leqslant4{\left(2-t\right)}\frac{t+2}{t^2+2}\text,\\\displaystyle wx+wy+wz+xy+xz+yz\geqslant\frac43{\left(4-t\right)}{\left(4-3t\right)}{\left(\frac{t+2}{t^2+2}\right)}^{\!2}\text,\\\displaystyle wxy+wxz+wyz+xyz-\frac{t^2+2}6wxyz\leqslant\frac{32}{27}{\left(4-t\right)}^2{\left(1-t\right)}{\left(\frac{t+2}{t^2+2}\right)}^{\!3}\text.\end{cases}$$ Note that the explicit values to the solutions are not required.
There exists an instant-use add-on function ResourceFunction["CountPolynomialSolutions"] in Mathematica, yet this function only accepts polynomial equations and just counts complex roots.  There also exist several related library functions in Maple, but the input of RootFinding:-Parametric:-CellsWithSolutions cannot be non-strict inequalities, and the input of RegularChains:-ParametricSystemTools:-RealRootClassification must involve at least one equation.
There are of course some numerical solvers dedicated to polynomial systems (such as HomotopyContinuation.jl, phcpy, and VerifyRealRoots); however, after some searching, none of them appear to support finding conditions of parameters.
So, is there a suitable package for this purpose?

As you have only inequalities, normally such a system would describe a $4$-dimensional set in $(x,y,z,w)$-space. Since you expect a finite number of points for $0<t<1$, there should be a good reason for this degeneracy, which probably could and should be worked out directly first. Also, your question apparently is about the coefficients of a monic degree $4$ polynomial with $4$ nonnegative roots, where the coefficients fulfill linear inequalities.

@PeterMueller Yes they are linear in the elementary symmetric polynomials of $w$, $x$, $y$, and $z$, but if so, there will exist another problem: $w,x,y,z\in\mathbb{R}_{\geqslant0}$ is not equivalent to the nonnegativity of the four elementary symmetric polynomials.

If an input must contain an equation, can you fool it with $x+y=y+x$? or, $(x+1)(x-1)-x^2=-1$?
